# Mysql Full Table Update Tunning

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make a full table (the size of test is more than 100 million) update as fast as possible? Dose mysql has similar parallel query like oracle?

The sql request is like:

```
update table test set col1 = DA(col1)
```

DA is some kind of deformation algorithm function.

It's not a 1-time task since we need to transfer data from production database to test database periodically. And some sensitive data columns neet to deformation (i.g. "ABC" to "!*#@*!" )before test user can use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updating all rows in a table is *very time-consuming*.  The reason has to do with locks and logging.

When doing a massive update, it is often faster to create a *new* table and then reload the old table.  Something like this:

```
create table temp_test as
    select DA(col1) as col1, . . .   -- rest of the columns
    from test;

truncate table test;                 -- stash the old copy before doing this!

insert into test ( . . . )           -- list the columns here
    select . . .                     -- list the columns here
    from temp_test;
```